# Error with flash as3

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

When I ran my application, I got the following error message:

```
Error #2044: Ej hanterad ioError:. text=Error #2032: Flödesfel. URL: file:///C|/wamp/www/PrototypFlash/guestbookParse.php/PrototypFlash
    at prototyp_fla::testimonials_33/frame1()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at BandsPage()
    at Main()
```

Unfortunately, I can't find the error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use debug mode in flash by pressing and holding CTRL + SHIFT + Enter/Return on your keyboard. When the error hits, it should take you to the line throwing the error.